# $\ker A=(\operatorname{im} A)^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a normal operator on $\mathbb C^n$. (Normal means $AA^\ast=A^\ast A$, where $A^\ast$ is the adjoint operator.) How do I show that $\ker A=(\operatorname{im} A)^\perp$? (Orthogonality is understood with respect to the standard complex dot product on $\mathbb C^n$.)

I cannot prove a single inclusion.

For example, let $x\in \ker A$. Let $y\in \operatorname{im} A$ so that $y=Az$. Need to prove $(x,y)=0$. $(x,y)=(x,Az)=(A^\ast x, z)$. But how to make use of the normality of $A$?

Comment: If $Ax = 0$, then $\langle Ax, Ax \rangle = \langle x, A^* A x \rangle = \langle x, A A^* x \rangle = \langle A^* x, A^* x \rangle = 0$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler You mean $x\in \ker A $ iff $x\in \ker A^\ast$, and then apply the fact that $\ker B=(\operatorname{im} B^\ast)^\perp$ for any matrix $B$?

Comment: Well, I was more referring to your equation $\langle x, y \rangle = \langle x, Az \rangle = \langle A^* x, z \rangle$, where my argument then shows $A^* x = 0$.  But, something like that should also work.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\in(\text{Im}A)^{\perp}$, then for all $z$, $\left<A^{\ast}x,z\right>=\left<x,Az\right>=0$, so $A^{\ast}x=0$. Then $\left<Ax,Ax\right>=\left<x,A^{\ast}Ax\right>=\left<x,AA^{\ast}x\right>=0$, so $Ax=0$, this proves $(\text{Im}A)^{\perp}\subseteq\ker A$.